# How can I find all solutions to the following differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx}=6x(y-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=6x(y-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

The algebra started getting very hairy, so I figured I was making a mistake somewhere, but here is what I did:

First I tried using separation of variables:

$$\frac{dy}{(y-1)^\frac{2}{3}}=6x\,dx$$

After integrating the two expressions I got:

$$3(y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}=3x^2+C$$

Am I heading in the right direction or did I make a mistake in approaching this problem?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's anything hairy about that, unless you were multiplying out $(3x^2+C)^3$.

Comment: @free_mind: How did it get to $(y-1)$? Otherwise, perfect.

Comment: This is perfectly correct ! Take care that the $2$ of the first equation became $1$ in the remaining. Don't forget to divide by $3$ at the end and finish the expression to get $y=2+(x^2+C)^3$

Comment: Do remember, that you may absorb one constant into another

Comment: Well, seems that $y\equiv 2$ should also be a solution.

Comment: This (classical) exercise is meant to make you reach an in-depth understanding of the so-called Cauchy-Lipschitz conditions, which ensure the existence and uniqueness of solutions in a neighborhood of the initial time, and which are not met here. In this context, answers "forgetting" solutions of the differential equation such as $y(x)=2$ for every $x<x_0$, for some nonnegative $x_0$, and $$y(x)=2+(x^2-x_0^2)^3$$ for every $x\geqslant x_0$, amongst tons of other similar ones, would be of little use.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{(y-1)^{2/3}}=6xdx$$ provided $y\neq1$ gives $y=\frac{1}{27}(3x^2+c)^3+1$ as general solution. Note that $y=1$ is also a *singular solution* to the given ODE which is not contained in the general solution.

Comment: I do not understand why downvote?

Comment: I obviously wasn't the one to downvote you, but did you have a typo (or perhaps I misunderstood something) with the $3(y-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$.  Shouldn't it be $3(y-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: Nevermind, I'm the one with the typo!